# Discount Calculations in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my gridview i am having sellprice,quantity,discount,netamount.
      the user enters the quantity and discount and the result should be displayed in the netamount column i am trying with this code it is not coming:

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            Label subtot;
            TextBox txtSerAmt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtServiceAmount");
            TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity");
            TextBox txtdsAmount = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdsAmount");
            TextBox TxtNetAmt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtNetAmt");

            if (txtSerAmt != null && txtQuantity != null && txtdsAmount != null)
            {
               TxtNetAmt.Text = (((
               Convert.ToDouble(txtSerAmt.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text))) * Convert.ToDouble(txtdsAmount.Text)/100).ToString();
            }
        }
```

this code i had written textchanged event help me to solve the problem..........

Comment: Re-tagged the question to include C# instead of c and .net instead of dot

Answer (score 0):

Are the TextBox controls named as in your sample? Just take another look at that, because some of them are named with a capital letter at the beginning and some not. Maybe you mixed up the names. C# is case-sensitive.